# [disabled]="!isValid()" is not working in IE11 for Angular 8

Tags: angular, validation, angular8, disabled-control

disabled attribute with function is not working in IE11. It remains disable all the time. Please refer below code:

HTML:

```
 <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!isValid()">SAVE</button>
```

Component (.ts)

```
isValid(){
    return this.providedId != null;
}
```

Comment: Just curious: have you tried with `[attr.disabled]` maybe?

Comment: Yes, ```[attr.disabled]``` is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working with a `getter`, so you won't need the parentheses inside the template:

```
get isValid(){
    return this.providedId != null;  
    // Or any other complicated logic...
}
```

And the template without the parentheses:

```
<button [disabled]="!isValid">SAVE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need that function `isValid()`? Are you having more logic in there?

Otherwise you can directly bind to `providedId`:

```
<button [disabled]="!providedId">
I am a button
</button>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-disabled-binding